# Do you always need to parametrise to solve a line integral?

Tags: integration, parametric, line-integrals

For example, to calculate:
$$\int_{C} (6x+z) dl,$$
where C is the straight line from $(0,0,0)$ to $(0,0,1)$, would I have to parametrise or is there an alternative method?

Comment: Suppose you have an integral, say along the x-axis, from 5 to 6. Then by choosing dx as the line element, you have implicitly parametrised the problem. Here, there’s an obvious parametrisation. In more complicated line-integrals, such as contour integrals, there are methods to solve them using the Residue Theorem.

Comment: Understood, thanks.